# Japanese file name listing in shell script, how to avoid unexpected enter escape line

Tags: bash, shell, glob

What I want is getting the file name one by one from the directory. The thing is, all file names are written in Japanese, which I am not familiar with, neither my Mac is.

So when I list the file name using `ls`, then I got this:

```
Ｋ’ｓマンション.jpg
Ｌｅーｌｉｏｎ Ｖｒａｎｃｈｅ’ 日暮里 Ｅａｓｔ.jpg
ＭＡＸＩＶ高島平.jpg
ＭＯＲＥ国立.jpg
ＯＬＩＯ上北沢.jpg
ＯＬＩＯ世田谷上野毛 .jpg
ＯＬＩＯ世田谷上野毛.jpg
ＯＬＩＯ渋谷西原 .jpg
ＰＩＥＲ上高田.jpg
Ｒiche   Ｎ・Ｋ.jpg
ＲＥＶ　ＵＮ.jpg
ＳＩＮーＣｉｔｙ上北沢ＸＥＢＥＣ.jpg
ＳＩＮ－Ｃｉｔｙ本蓮沼ＢＥＬＬＧＲＡＤＥ.jpg
```

And when I use a shell script to get each file name using

```
for FILENAME in `ls *.jpg`; do
  echo $FILENAME
done
```

, then I got these:

```
ＡＤＸ新宿河田町
.jpg
ＡＲＡＩ
.jpg
ＣＲＥＶＩＳＴＡ北千住.jpg
ＤＲホームズ大山
.jpg
ＧＥＮＯＶＩＡＨＩＬＬＳ西馬込ＲＯＳＳＯ.jpg
Ｋ’ｓマンション.jpg
Ｌｅーｌｉｏｎ
Ｖｒａｎｃｈｅ’
日暮里
Ｅａｓｔ.jpg
ＭＡＸＩＶ高島平.jpg
ＭＯＲＥ国立.jpg
ＯＬＩＯ上北沢.jpg
ＯＬＩＯ世田谷上野毛
.jpg
ＯＬＩＯ世田谷上野毛.jpg
ＯＬＩＯ渋谷西原
.jpg
ＰＩＥＲ上高田.jpg
Ｒiche
Ｎ・Ｋ.jpg
ＲＥＶ　ＵＮ.jpg
ＳＩＮーＣｉｔｙ上北沢ＸＥＢＥＣ.jpg
ＳＩＮ－Ｃｉｔｙ本蓮沼ＢＥＬＬＧＲＡＤＥ.jpg
```

How can I resolve this issue? I really get the file name as it is since I need to do something with it.

Comment: What about `for FILENAME in *.jpg; do echo "$FILENAME"; done`?

Comment: @Sharad The question not about Python and not about Windows so no duplication.

Comment: I suggest `for filename in *.jpg; do echo "$filename"; done`. See: [Bash Pitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Not a brilliant duplicate but [the answer which says don't use `ls`](/a/19959895/874188) should fix your problems.